# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' in python

Tags: python

When I am calling the below method I am getting error as

```
line 152, in get_resources_by_filter_context_associated_components
    new_id = parse.quote_from_bytes((id.encode("utf-8")), safe="")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

---

```
 def get_resources_by_filter_context_associated_components(self, providers=None,account_number=None,
                                                              business_unit=None, environment=None,
                                                              availability=None, risk=None, sort_by='provider_code',
                                                              page='1', size="10",
                                                              application=None, id=None, header_value=True):
        """
 new_id = parse.quote_from_bytes((id.encode("utf-8")), safe="")
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the caller does not pass a value for `id`?

Comment: This error indicates that the value of "id" is None (not set) when you call "parse.quote_from_bytes((..".